# Xamarin ContentView on screen center

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentView element of this structure:

```
<ContentView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
        <ActivityIndicator>
            ...
        </ActivityIndicator>
    </StackLayout> 
</ContentView>
```

and i need to put it on the center of a page. I am new to WPF and i don't know how to do it. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Did you try with `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` ?

Comment: Is this question about **WPF** or **Xamarin.Forms**? Please remove the tag that misfits.

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on Shiblu's response

Comment: My bad, i removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Center as LayoutOptions for the ContentView

```
<ContentView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
        <ActivityIndicator>
            ...
        </ActivityIndicator>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this and the ContentView is centered on the horizontal axis but on the vertical axis it is not. It starts from the middle of the screen and goes down. So, if the ContentView is 200*300, and the screen is 1000*1000, the ContentView will have 500 px above him and 200 px bellow him

Comment: You didn't mention the height and width request of the content view. As stated by your answer you I guess you could offset the vertical option by putting margin. It would be better if you show us the ContentPage where you put this ContentvVew along with the full code for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My problem with Shiblu'a answer was that the ContentView was centered on the horizontal axis but on the vertical axis it was not. It started from the middle of the screen and went down. So, if the ContentView was 200*300, and the screen was 1000*1000, the ContentView will have 500 px above him and 200 px bellow him. I have corrected that with a negative Margin value

```
<ContentView HeightRequest="170" WidthRequest="450" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0, -85, 0, 0">
  <StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
    <ActivityIndicator>
        ...
    </ActivityIndicator>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```